# How to turn off Excel addins?

Tags: excel, excel-addins, group-policy

I have about 3 or 4 Excel addins.  If I try to disable them from Excel Options > Addins > Manage > COM Addins > untick then I get a message that only an administrator can do this.

Can Excel be started as Admin?

If not where could the addins be hiding?

They are not here

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins

or here

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins

The Windows 7 x64 PC is managed under Group Policy so is there somewhere else where they can be?  They are not VSTO based addins as VSTO is not installed.

I obviously have access to the registry and can change anything in the registry.

Comment: You can right-click, Run As Administrator, on the Excel.exe itself.

Comment: I was trying to right click on the links which is why I did not see the Run as.  Once it is running as admin I can remove the addins.  If you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click, Run As Administrator, on the Excel.exe itself.

When running as as an Admin, you can remove the Add-Ins.